# C Help - Same variable with two values

Tags: c

I have a function with the input variables what are modified by this function ( this I can test and the variables in the end are right ) , the function are in the file1.c and is declared in file1.h , and I called this function by the main file ( main.c ) . But when in main.c I use this function , the variables are not modified .

For be more easy to understand, an exemple:

**In file1.c ->**

```
void funcion(char input1[], int input2){

--> Here some modificions happends

printf("Variables first are %c %d", input1[0], input2);
//the function end after this print

}
```

**In file1.h->**

```
void funcion(char input1[], int input2);
```

**In main.c->**

```
#include "file1.h"

main()
{
char *input1;
int input2;

function(input1, input2);
printf("Variables second are %c %d", input1[0], input2);
}
```

**The out put of the program:**

```
Variables first are A B

Variables second are C D
```

The variable A =/= C and B =/= D. Please, someone can help?

Comment: `printf("Variables first are %c %d", input1[0], input2);` would never print "Variables first are A B".   Post true code, data and expectations.

Comment: What do you expect to see, given that neither `input1` nor `input2` are initialized?

Comment: You have not allocated memory for the array input1.  That is one of the problem.

Comment: There are many duplicates of this, but the gist is that C passes variables *by value* and doesn't have passing *by reference* which is needed if you want to modify variables in a function and have that modification reflected in the caller. Do a search for e.g. *c emulate pass by reference*.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser, I will search the difference between "call by value" and "call by reference".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you have written has local copies of those variables, as you are not using call by reference. You are using call by value.  Hence, even if the function modifies the variables, those modifications are not done to the variables passed from the `main()`. They are done to the local copies of the variables whose scope is limited to that method.  Please read up the difference between "call by value" and "call by reference".

Comment: Thanks for the anwser, I will search the difference between "call by value" and "call by reference".